# How is hamzat-al-wasl pronounced at the beginning of an ayah?

Tags: arabic, tajweed

I know that at the beginning of a noun, when the *hamzat-al-wasl* in the definite article الْ is pronounced, it is always pronounced as "al-" (i.e. with a *fatha*).  However, using [Al-Fatihah 6](http://quran.com/1/6) as an example, the *hamzat-al-wasl* in اهْدِنَا is pronounced "ihdinaa" (i.e. with a *kasra*).

Visually, there is nothing to distinguish the *hamzat-al-wasl* in either case; they are both written exactly the same.  How should one know which vowel to pronounce when the *hamzat-al-wasl* comes at the beginning of an *ayah* (i.e. is not absorbed into the preceding vowel), or is it just a matter of learning and memorizing how each word would be pronounced when it comes up?

Answer (score 4):

The pronunciation of *hamzat-al-wasl* is regular, and can be predicted with some basic knowledge of Arabic grammar.  There are <strike>three</strike> four cases in particular:

1. **The definite prefix "al-" (ال)**: This is always pronounced with a *fatha*.
2. **Nouns in general**: Any noun which starts with a *hamzat-al-wasl* (not including the definite "al-" mentioned above) would be pronounced with a *kasra*.
3. **Regular verbs**:  All regular verbs which start with a *hamzat-al-wasl* would be pronounced according to the vowel on the *third letter* of the verb:

   1. If the third letter of the verb is a *fatha* or a *kasra*, the *hamzat-al-wasl* would be pronounced with a *kasra*.
   2. If the third letter of the verb is a natural *damma*, the *hamzat-al-wasl* would be pronounced with a *damma*.
4. **Irregular verbs**: This is really the same as the regular verbs rule, but you need to know the *natural* vowel on the third letter rather than the *presented* vowel.  There are five examples in the Qur'an (امضوا ، ائتوا ، امشوا ، ابنوا ، اقضوا) where the third vowel is *presented* as a *damma*, but the *hamzat-al-wasl* is pronounced with a *kasra* (i.e. as if the vowel on the third letter were either a *kasra* or a *fatha*).